# Does Source Based Linux Distro's Have Lower Download Size for Packages Rather Than Binary?

Tags: linux, source, binary

I looked all over the internet and couldn't find the answer to my question. If you use a source based distro, does that lower download sizes, compared to binary? If so, how significant is it? (Provide an example if you could).

I have slow internet and I would like to cut downloading time and rather use that time to compile.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally not, the source code and related resources are very often much larger than the binary products.

An example (from Gentoo): Google's Chromium source tarball is about 208M (`.tar.bz2`), the binary package created after install is ~35M (same compression).